# How to modify page URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How can you modify the URL for the current page that gets passed to Google Analytics?

(I need to strip the extensions from certain pages because for different cases a page can be requested with or without it and GA sees this as two different pages.)

For example, if the page URL is `http://mysite/cake/ilikecake.html`, how can I pass to google analytics `http://mysite/cake/ilikecake` instead?

I can strip the extension fine, I just can't figure out how to pass the URL I want to Google Analytics.  I've tried this, but the stats in the Google Analytics console don't show any page views:

> pageTracker._trackPageview('cake/ilikecake');

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Did you check your browser's JavaScript error console? Everything is okay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. it can take a while, up to about 24 hours, for visits to be reflected in the Analytics statistics. How long ago did you make your change?
2. try beginning the pathname with a "/", so

   ```
   pageTracker._trackPageview('/cake/ilikecake');
   ```

   and then wait a bit, as per the first item.

Answer (score 9):

You could edit the GA profile and add custom filters ...

Create a 'Search and Replace' custom filter, setting the filter field to 'Request URI' and using something like:

Search String:    `(.*ilikecake\.)html$`

Replace String:   `$1`
  (was `\1`)

Comment: Or use (.*)\.html$ to strip the extension from all .html urls.

Comment: i would go with pageTracker._trackPageview ... it would keep things more organized then having filters. plus you have to add the to all your profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you have the ga script code at the end of your file, while special _trackPageviews() calls are often used somewhere else.

Have you made sure you have your call to pageTracker._trackPageview() after you have defined the pagetracker?

Like this:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

otherwise you just get a JavaScript error I suppose.